# SqlExceptionHelper - The column name ... was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, sqlexception

This is the query:

```
UPDATE einvoice_message AS e1 
  SET message = null 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM einvoice_message 
  where created < :created 
  ORDER BY :created LIMIT :limit 
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
) AS e2 
WHERE e1.einvoice_message_id = e2.einvoice_message_id 
RETURNING e1.einvoice_message_id
```

I'm getting `SqlExceptionHelper - The column name created was not found in this ResultSet.` Don't understand why and where? Need help.

Java code:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE einvoice_message AS e1 SET message = null FROM (SELECT * FROM einvoice_message 
where created < :created ORDER BY :created LIMIT :limit FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) AS e2 WHERE 
e1.einvoice_message_id = e2.einvoice_message_id RETURNING e1.einvoice_message_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<EinvoiceMessage> deleteEinvoiceMessageContent(@Param("created") OffsetDateTime created, 
@Param("limit") int limit);
```

Here is my table ddl:

```
create table einvoice_message
(
    einvoice_message_id bigserial not null
        constraint einvoice_message_pk
            primary key,
    message bytea not null,
    created timestamp default now() not null
);
```

Changing `:created` variable to column `created` didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I guess you should add the Java code you are using.

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the return value of this. `RETURNING e1.einvoice_message_id` will return a number not a List as I've mentioned. The correct answer would be:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE einvoice_message AS e1 SET message = null FROM (SELECT * FROM einvoice_message 
where created < :created ORDER BY :created LIMIT :limit FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) AS e2 WHERE 
e1.einvoice_message_id = e2.einvoice_message_id RETURNING e1.einvoice_message_id", nativeQuery = true)
int deleteEinvoiceMessageContent(@Param("created") OffsetDateTime created, 
@Param("limit") int limit);
```